# Submitting form to correct URL in ASP.net using BaseHREF

Tags: asp.net, url, post, webforms, base-tag

For unavoidable design reasons, in my head tag on my top level `MasterPage` I have:

```
<base href="http://127.0.0.1/" />
```

The URL of the page I'm having difficulties with is:

```
http://127.0.0.1/store/checkout
```

On this `content page` I have the control:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Payment ▶" />
```

However when clicked, it posts the form to:

```
http://127.0.0.1/checkout
```

Which throws a 404, as it is not `store/checkout` as it should be.

How can I resolve this issue so that the form is posted to the correct URL, AND it **must** degrade gracefully so that if JS is disabled it will post correctly, which is why unfortunately I cannot accept any Javascript solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Doh!  I've been struggling with this for days and have just stumbled across the answer.

On the master page I created a new method:

```
public void changeFormAction(string Action)
{
    MainForm.Action = Action;
}
```

Then from the content page I call:

```
Master.changeFormAction("/store/checkout");
```

This fixes it!